# Calling IE Js Debugger from JS

Tags: javascript, debugging, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am developing this MSCRM2011 tool:

https://mscrmjscodeevaluator.codeplex.com/

Basically, it runs JS code on the current CRM window. The advantage of this is that you can run code, within the current context.

Now, I thought it would be nice to have a way to easily debug this code, so, my questions:

1. There is an easy way to call the IE developer tools (F12) from js, and say to it "debug this chunk of code"??
2. If not 1), is there a way (easy or not) to debug javascript, within any third-party "integratable" debugger, or something like this that allows me to have some control of the debugging process??

Comment: The `debugger;` statement *might* work in IE. The IE developer tools before IE8 were borderline useless, so it doesn't really matter whether it works there :-)

Comment: ... well it doesn't seem to work in IE8; I'll try 9.

Comment: ... oh well it *does* work in IE if you've clicked the "Start Debugging" button.  Gee thanks Microsoft :-)

Comment: @Pointy, All browser will skip `debugger` statements if they don't have a debugger console open.

Comment: @Pilgrim when I tried it in Firefox, it opened Firebug in a window where it wasn't open. I'll try again however. *edit* hmm your right; well I don't think I'm crazy; it *did* open up Firebug before ... must be some change I did and but didn't pay attention to

Answer (score 0):

With Developer Tools, you can just prepend your code with `frames[0].`

http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2012/02/xrm-2011-javascript-another-101-lesson.html

http://blog.customereffective.com/blog/2011/02/internet-explorer-developer-tools.html

Additionally, you can browse the DOM really easily, modify CSS attributes, etc.

I like the tool you've added though and think it's a great addition.  Syntax highlighting is a great feature you have and its missing from developer tools.